# `use` and `crate` keywords not work well in rust project

Tags: rust

I have a project named use_tutorial and project structure is listed in here.

use_tutorial

- src

  - lib.rs
  - main.rs

lib.rs content is:

```
pub trait Draw {
  fn draw(&self);
}
```

main.rs cotnent is:

```
use crate::Draw;
// use use_tutorial::Draw;
// use super::Draw;
struct SelectBox {
  width: u32,
  height: u32,
  options: Vec<String>
},
impl Draw for SelectBox {
  fn draw(&self) {
    println!("SelectBox draw");
  }
}
fn main() {
  //....
}
```

When the use statements is `use use_tutorial::Draw`, it works well.
But When the use statements is `use crate::Draw` or `use super::Draw`, it doesn't work well.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be mixing the concepts of crates and modules.

Your project has two crates each with just one source code file and one single module:

- The `lib.rs` is named `use_tutorial`, type *library*.
- The `main.rs` is named `bin` (I think), and it is of type *binary*.

Additionally the `use_tutorial` crate has a public name `Draw`, its full name is `use_tutorial::Draw`.

So when in the binary crate you write `use use_tutorial::Draw` it works fine, as expected.

But when you write `use crate::Draw` it looks for the `Draw` name in the root of the current crate, that is what `crate::` means, but the current crate is `bin` and there is no such name there, hence the error.

And when you write `use super::Draw` the compiler loos for the supermodule of the current module, but you are writing it in `main.rs` that is the top module of its crate, so `super::` just means nothing.

Comment: The default name of the binary crate in this situation is *also* `use_tutorial`. (But it doesn't matter to the outcome because it is not a library.)

Comment: If I want to swap the contents of two files, how should I write the use statements?
What I mean is that lib.rs import something from main.rs

Comment: @flywen: You can't do that, a binary crate, by definition, doesn't export anything, and can't be referenced by any other crate. Maybe you are using crates where you want to use modules? You can totally have two modules that reference each other.